# get out from git repository (VScode)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using both remote connection in VSCode and GitHub. Usually, I would clone my project in "source control" using a URL.
Every time I close the connection, I would automatically "get out" from the git repository.

Today, I used "clone repository" in "explorer", then VSCode started showing 6000+ changes in "source control": they are the old files I stored in my remote folder(nothing about the URL I just cloned).

How can I get out from this status? (or get out from the git repository ?)
(All folders are showing "green U" except the one containing my cloned project)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

To get out of Git on Visual Studio Code (on any platform), click on the account symbol (above the cog icon for Settings on the bottom of the left-hand side toolbar), and click *Log out*. This should log you out of your account.

---

If you are talking about ignoring the files, then add the following in `.gitignore` (in the folder you want to ignore).

```
*
*/
!.gitignore
```

The first line informs Git to ignore all files in the folder, but add `.gitignore`, as specified in the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Check first if your "clone from Explorer" did not clone the repository in a wrong path, meaning one folder below or above the folder monitored by your Remote VSCode session.

VSCode would then display old files (from the old clone) as well as files from the cloned repository done in the wrong path.

The best remedy would be to open an SSH session and look for yourself (not through VSCode) in command-line, to see what is going on.
Ideally, you could simply remove any extra folder, and reclone everything, then open the cloned repo through Remote VSCode.